# Spark UDF throws NullPointerException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have spark UDF, which I call from the SQL statement. This is how I have defined and register UDF function:

**UDF:**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf


def udf_temp_emp (_type: String, _name: String): Int  = {

   val statement = s"select key from employee where empName = $_name"

   val key = spark.sql(statement).collect()(0).getInt(0)
   return key
}

spark.udf.register("udf_temp_emp", udf_temp_emp(_,_))
```

And this is how I call it in my SQL command:

```
select 
  udf_temp_emp(emp.type, emp.name), 
  emp.id 
from 
   empMaster
```

And when I run above command, it throws below exception:

> SparkException: [FAILED_EXECUTE_UDF] Failed to execute user defined
> function
> ($read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$Lambda$13841/67716274:
> (string, string) => string). Caused by: NullPointerException:

Comment: You cannot use the Spark session inside of an udf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

per werner's comment (should be an answer and the selected one at that) this isn't possible as the SparkContext / SparkSession doesn't exist on the executor nodes.  The only time this "works" is if you use LocalRelations (such as a converted Seq).

Re-write your udf as a join, assuming that is the actual logic.

Comment: Great. This was new to me being a newbie in dataengineering.

Comment: Don't feel like you missed something, it hits everyone and often in unexpected ways: [accidentally registering the udf on the executor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76882963/problems-in-udf-function-in-spark-3-3-scala/76885134#76885134) or the [LocalRelation pitfall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76863662/fitting-logisticregression-within-a-user-defined-fuction-udf/76867542#76867542)